# Call to a member function find() on null in Cakephp2.10

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got below error when I am trying to update my project ***Cakephp1.x to Cakephp2.10***

> Call to a member function find() on null

Please help me to fix this.

This is my code

```
$list   =   $this->Category->find('all',array('order' => array('position' => 'ASC')));
```

Comment: Can show us your function where you are calling `find()` method

Comment: code is added. Please have a look

Comment: I think you forget to load the Category model in your controller.

Comment: `$this->loadModel('Category');` add this

Comment: thanks, it's working

Answer (score 0):

$this->set('names', $this->loadModel('Name'));
$this->set('names', $this->Name->find('all'));

//name is just an example provide with your reference